# Why does the GUI of Matlab's nntraintool still show although net.trainParam.showWindow = 0?

Tags: matlab, nntool

I came across this issue when I tried to suppress the GUI called by train() following this answer:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81073-how-to-close-nntrain-tool

So right after creating my net I disabled the GUI:

`net = narxnet(...)
 net.trainParam.showWindow = 0;`

Unfortunately, it would still pop up! Why?

Comment: This is the Q&A version of the more basic problem I asked about in another question I just deleted because I thought that it is more helpful for other people in this form. Should anyone ever come across the answer to why this issue exists, i.e. if there is a sensible reason for net.trainFcn overwriting this parameter or if it is a bug, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking the variable's behaviour shows that it remains (while setting data division etc. following one of the automatically produced scripts provided by nntool) 0 until

`net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';`

is called which changes net.trainParam.showWindow's value back to 1. Therefore, in order to make sure that the GUI does not pop up setting this variable to 0 should happen right before train() is called.